# SlickGrid JQuery plugin - Copy data from one spreadsheet to a second spreadsheet on the same web page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, spreadsheet, slickgrid

I am creating a web application which contains two SlickGrid plugins ( in the spreadsheet excel like format) on the same page divided by a Slider plugin.  Is there any way to copy data from cells of the first spreadsheet to the second spreadsheet on the same page?  This is the requirements of our customer.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace all the data from one grid with the data in the other grid, then this will work:

```
grid2.setData(grid1.getData());
grid2.invalidate();
```

If you need to append the data from one grid to the data in the other grid, retaining the data that was already in the grid, this should work:

```
var grid1Data = grid1.getData();
var grid2Data = grid2.getData();

for(var i = 0; i < grid1Data.length; i++) {
    grid2Data.push(grid1Data[i]);
}
grid2.setData(grid2Data);
grid2.invalidate();
```